# How do i edit home page of magento

Tags: php, magento

[image]

Hello guys can please anyone suggest me how do i edit the black marked tabs in image through code,(the path for the code of this tabs)

Comment: Try looking at the one column phtml file to see what is being called in where, or perhaps the home CMS page in the admin system if it exists

Comment: you are not new to SO. clearly mention the problem and share the code you tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you ever worked with Magento? have you worked yourself into the Magento templating system?

Comment: hello guys this is my home page picture,and here it showing only one product,i need it to show new products,when i click in to the new products in the tab its showing good,so how do i default make new product tab as active

Comment: Please check your Home Cms page in the admin. If there is a block for that tab, you might update that block. Or if there is content to show that tags, you have to change that code. Add your active class to the product tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First please check from where the content of the home is come from.
you can you template path for it.
if its comes from CMS Page you can edit form the admin CMS page.
if its a comes from Static block you can change it from the CMS blocks in admin.
and if its a hardcode in phtml file or any xyz.phtml file call in home then you have to edit that xyz.phtml file.